# How to interpret the graph?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

It is about vector addition! I can not see how $x$ and $y$ connect with $x+y$, intuitively,cut a small triangle near $y-$axis and transfer to $(b_1,b_2)$, please use analytic geometry to interpret it. In other words, use $xy$-plane coordinate system to interpret. I know how parallelogram law works for this graph[image: vector addition]

Comment: This is the parallelogram law. Does the name suggest you anything?

Comment: @StefanOctavian I know how the law works. I don’t know how to interpret it by x-y plane coordinate system knowledge

Comment: Well, $x+y$ is obtained by adding the first coordinates of $x$ and $y$ and also adding the second coordinates of $x$ and $y$: $x+y = (a_1, a_2) + (b_1, b_2) = (a_1+b_1, a_2 + b_2)$. Does that answer your question? Otherwise, you need to be clearer about what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0):

What is being demonstrated here is that by the Parallelogram definition for vector addition, the coordinates of $x + y$ are the sums of the coordinates of $x$ and $y$.

They did not just "cut *a* small triangle". What they did was copy the *particular* triangle $\triangle PUV$
[image]

This is a right triangle with the $x$ vector as its hypotenuse. The vertical leg has length $a_2$, while the shorter leg has length $a_1$.

If you rotate this triangle by $180^\circ$, the three sides of the resultant triangle $\triangle P'U'V'$  will be parallel to their originals. The horizontal leg will still be horizontal, the vertical leg still vertical, and the hypotenuse will still be parallel to the $x$ vector.

Next translate $\triangle P'U'V'$ until $U'$ coincides with the end of the vector $y$, resulting in a third triangle $\triangle P''U''V''$. The hypotenuse is still parallel to $x$ and of the same length. But the right side of the parallelogram also has its endpoint at $y$, and is parallel to and of the same length as $x$. Thus the hypotenuse of $\triangle P''U''V''$ and the right side of the parallelogram must be the same, and $\triangle P''U''V''$ has to be as shown in the diagram, with $P'' = Q$.

The horizontal leg $\overline{U''V''}$ is horizontal and has length $a_1$. Since $U''$ is the end of $y$, it has coordinates $(b_1, b_2)$, so moving horizontally a distance of $a_1$ puts $V''$ at $(a_1 + b_1, b_2)$. The vertical leg $\overline{QV''}$ has length $a_2$, and moving vertically a distance of $a_2$ from $V''$ gives coordinates $(a_1 + b_1, a_2 + b_2)$. Thus $Q = (a_1 + b_1, a_2 + b_2)$.